# Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am importing csv file in Neo4j with the following code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///datafile.csv" AS row 
MERGE (u:User {id: toInt(row[0])}) 
MERGE (t:Team {id: toInt(row[1])})
MERGE (c:TeamChatSession {id: toInt(row[2])}) 
MERGE (u)-[:CreatesSession{timeStamp: row[3]}]->(c) 
MERGE (c)-[:OwnedBy{timeStamp: row[3]}]->(t)
```

and I got this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Expected Long(0) to be a 
org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a 
org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue
```

Here is an overview of the file I am importing.

```
1588,177,6776,1464233999.0
350,188,6777,1464234000.0
1588,177,6776,1464233999.0
350,188,6777,1464234000.0
740,81,6778,1464234001.0
1068,66,6779,1464234002.0
1554,52,6780,1464234003.0
```

Please help.

Comment: Please, edit your file with a text editor and paste a raw text instead of a Excel screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSV file has no header, but your query specifies the `WITH HEADERS` option. Try again after removing that option.

*Also, the `TOINT()` function is deprecated. You should use `TOINTEGER()` instead.*

*And, if your other queries want to treat the `timestamp` property values as a numeric value, you should use `TOINTEGER` to convert the `row[3]` value as well, so that your other queries will not have to always do the same conversion.*

Comment: I was able to import with the following code:

    LOAD CSV FROM "file:///datafile.csv" AS row 
    MERGE (u:User {id: toInteger(row[0])}) 
    MERGE (t:Team {id: toInteger(row[1])})
    MERGE (c:TeamChatSession {id: toInteger(row[2])}) 
    MERGE (u)-[:CreatesSession{timeStamp: toInteger(row[3])}]->(c) 
    MERGE (c)-[:OwnedBy{timeStamp: toInteger(row[3])}]->(t)

Thank you so much!